# Js inheritance and instanceof

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain why we have this behavior? I understand that it should act like this, *but i can't explain*

```
function foo() {}

function foo1() {}

foo.prototype = foo1.prototype = {};

var _foo = new foo();

alert( _foo instanceof foo1 ); // true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, working with objects.

I think that is easier to understand if you compare this to more familiar objects

```
//defines a "class" Person
function Person() {} 

//defines a "class" Animal
function Animal() {}
```

Change `Animal` and `Person` prototype

```
Person.prototype = Animal.prototype = {};
```

prototype could be used to extend "class", example

```
function Person(name){
    this.name=name;
}

Person.prototype.nameInUperCase=function(){
    return this.name.toUpperCase();
}
```

Instantiate

```
var myPerson = new Person();
```

Check if my person is instance of.

```
// true because you instantiate the same prototype
// remember Person.prototype = Animal.prototype = {};
alert(myPerson instanceof Animal);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `instanceof` operator checks to see if the left-hand operand is an object that has on its prototype chain the prototype object of the right-hand operand. Since both your functions share the same prototype object, an instance of one is considered an instance of the other.

Answer (score 1):

`o instanceof f` checks to see if the object referenced by `f.prototype` appears anywhere in the prototype chain of `o`. In your case, since both `foo.prototype` and `foo1.prototype` refer to the same object, any object created via `new foo` or `new foo1` will be `instanceof` both `foo` and `foo1`.

This is covered in the following sections of the spec: [Runtime Semantics: InstanceofOperator(O, C)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-instanceofoperator), [Function.prototype[@@hasInstance] ( V )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype-@@hasinstance), and [OrdinaryHasInstance (C, O)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinaryhasinstance), with most of the work being done in that last link, Steps 4 through 7 (7 has substeps for the loop through `o`'s prototype chain).